# No extension exist for sourceMapper:xml , when using WS02 siddhi MQTT extension

Tags: xml, wso2, siddhi

I want to create an MQTT source in siddhi, My code for that is

```
public class MqttReceiver {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MqttReceiver.class);

    /**
     * Main method to start the test client.
     *
     * @param args no args need to be provided
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        log.info("Initialize mqtt receiver.");

        SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();

//        String url = "tcp://localhost:5020";
//        String topic = "mqtt_topic";
//        String type = "xml";


        SiddhiAppRuntime siddhiAppRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(
                "@App:name(\"PublishMqttInXmlFormatTest\")\n" +
                        "@source(type='mqtt', url= 'tcp://localhost:1883', topic='mqtt_topic', clean.session='true',quality.of.service= '1', keep.alive= '60',connection.timeout='30' , @map(type='xml'))" +
                        "define stream LowProducitonAlertStream (name string, amount double);\n" +
                        "@sink(type='log')\n" +
                        "define stream logStream(name string, amount double);\n" +
                        "from LowProducitonAlertStream\n" +
                        "select * \n" +
                        "insert into logStream;");



        siddhiAppRuntime.start();

        while (true) {
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting the following exception

```
No extension exist for sourceMapper:xml
```

it is evident from below image that `XML` is given as an example in the library files

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

---

### EDIT 1

It seems that `name parameter` for `type` is not mentioned in library file, but it is mentioned in example and [api](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-mqtt/api/1.0.17/#mqtt-source)

```
@Extension(
    name = "mqtt",
    namespace = "source",
    description = "The MQTT source receives the events from an MQTT broker ",
    parameters = {@Parameter(
    name = "url",
    description = "The URL of the MQTT broker. It is used to connect to the MQTT broker. It is required to specify a valid URL here.",
    type = {DataType.STRING}
), @Parameter(
    name = "username",
    description = "The username to be provided when the MQTT client is authenticated by the broker.",
    type = {DataType.STRING},
    optional = true,
    defaultValue = "null"
), @Parameter(
    name = "password",
    description = "The password to be provided when the MQTT client is authenticated by the broker.",
    type = {DataType.STRING},
    optional = true,
    defaultValue = "empty"
), @Parameter(
    name = "client.id",
    description = "A unique ID for the MQTT client. The server uses this to identify the client when it reconnects. If you do not specify a client ID, the system automatically generates it.",
    type = {DataType.STRING}
), @Parameter(
    name = "topic",
    description = "The topic from which WSO2 SP receives events via MQTT. Multiple topics can be specified as a list of comma separated values.This is a mandatory parameter.",
    type = {DataType.STRING}
), @Parameter(
    name = "quality.of.service",
    description = "The quality of service provided by the MQTT client. The possible values are as follows.`0`: The MQTT client sends each event to WSO2 SP only once. It does not receive an acknowledgement when an event is delivered, and the events are not stored.Events may get lost if the MQTT client is disconnected or if the server fails.This is the fastest method in which events are received via MQTT.`1`: The MQTT client sends each event to WSO2 SP at least once. If the MQTT client does not receive an acknowledgement to indicate that the event is delivered, it sends the event again.`2`: The MQTT client sends each event to WSO2 SP only once. The events are stored until the WSO2 SP receives them. This is the safest, but the slowest method of receiving events via MQTT.",
    type = {DataType.STRING},
    optional = true,
    defaultValue = "1"
), @Parameter(
    name = "clean.session",
    description = "This is an optional paramater. If this parameter is set to `true`, the subscriptions made by the MQTT client during a session expire when the session ends,and they need to be recreated for the next session.\nIf this parameter is set to `false`, all the information relating to the MQTT client's connection to the broker (e.g., the specific topics to which the client has subscribed) are saved after a session. Thus, when a session ends and restarts, the connection is re-established with the same information.\nThe default value is `true`.",
    type = {DataType.BOOL},
    optional = true,
    defaultValue = "true"
), @Parameter(
    name = "keep.alive",
    description = "The maximum number of seconds the connection between the MQTT client and the broker should be maintained without any events being transferred. Once this time interval elapses without any event transfers, the connection is dropped. The default value is 60.",
    type = {DataType.INT},
    optional = true,
    defaultValue = "60"
), @Parameter(
    name = "connection.timeout",
    description = "The maximum number of seconds that the MQTT client should spend attempting to connect to the MQTT broker. Once this time interval elapses, a timeout takes place.",
    type = {DataType.INT},
    optional = true,
    defaultValue = "30"
)},
```

How to use MQTT in siddhi ?

Answer (score 1):

after banging my head against the screen for an hour, I figured it was all my mistake, actually, `@map json` is another extension that needs to be imported into maven POM. So if you have this issue, put [this dependency](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-map-json/) in POM

Comment: Please also report if the error is not clear, I suppose it should have reported "No extension exist for sinkMapper:json"